# Set opacity of Highcharts pie chart

Tags: css, internet-explorer, opacity, highcharts, pie-chart

I have an issue with IE8, while set opacity of a pie chart. I tried as follow,

```
.highcharts-point {
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
```

When applied this, the pie chart points became not visible and their borders became grey color.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: If you have found the solution then it's good to post it as an answer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this, http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7622 and resolved my problem

Answer (score 4):

You can set the color of series:

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
         defaultSeriesType: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['1','2']
      },
      plotOptions: {
         column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
         }
      },
           series: [{
         name: 'Tokyo',
         data: [95.6, 54.4]

      }, {
         name: 'New York',
         data: [106.6, 92.3]

      }, {
         name: 'London',
         data: [59.3, 51.2]

      }, {
         name: 'Berlin',
         data: [46.8, 51.1],
         color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.5)'

      }]
   });


});
```

Note the last series defined there with color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     defaultSeriesType: 'column',
     type: 'area', //this is also needed
  },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            fillOpacity: 0.1
        }
    }, ...
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4HkXf/1/